# Can I send a url link in the caption in Instagram which can be tapped by the user

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, instagram

I am using a photo app that shares a photo and a caption with the Instagram app. Everything is working fine except for the fact that I am not able to tap the caption(which is a URL) in Instagram. Is it even possible to do so.? If YES, any help would be appreciated

Here's the way I set the annotation:

```
self.docController.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption" : caption};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently you cannot click on a link or URL in Instagram from the caption or comments section.  It's done to reduce spam. Keeping links as no-follow, and going a step further and having them non-clickable is a good way to deter spammers from posting links on users photos.

This is not written in the Documentation or in the Terms of Use, but you can simply try to add the link manually in your photo description - it will be non-clickable. There are a couple of questions and articles over the internet, all of them give the same answer: the only place for clickable link is your profile. Here is [one of them](http://daveamirault.com/post/55705791119/stop-doing-this-instagram-caption-links).

The only thing you can do - is to use caption with special hashtags, which are close to your app name. E.G.:

> This photo was taken with #GreatPhotoApp .

Comment: Can you please tell me a place where it is officially written.?

Comment: It's not written anywhere in the documentation. Look into my updated answer.